# behaviour of changing [].__proto__.constructor and [].constructor differs

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, prototype

I'm currently trying to understand the `constructor` property in javascript.

Just a heads up, I understand changing the properties of builtin should be avoided, I'm playing around with it because I want to better understand the underlying principles.

I tried to change the default `constructor` property of `[]` (i.e. default constructor for array objects)

```
[].__proto__.constructor === [].constructor; // true 

[].constructor = function A(){}; // attempts to reset the constructor property to a new function 

[].constructor; // prints ƒ Array() { [native code] }, which indicate the attempt failed
```

But when I checked the property descriptor of `[].constructor`

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor([].__proto__, 'constructor');
```

which prints

```
{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

So the `[].__proto__.constructor` property is `writable`?

So I tries to set the `constructor` property via `[].__proto__`, it succeeded

```
[].__proto__.constructor = function B(){};

[].__proto__.constructor; //   prints: ƒ B(){}, which indicate the attempt succeded
```

Why changing the `constructor` property via `[]` failed but via `[].__proto__` succeeded? Even though `[].constructor === [].__proto__.constructor` returned `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to property shadowing on the prototype chain. When you execute

```
[].constructor = ...;
```

this creates an instance property on the array that *shadows* the class prototype constructor. However, since `Array.prototype` already has its own `constructor` property, executing

```
[].__proto__.constructor = ...;
```

overwrites the constructor on `Array.prototype`.

You can confirm this behavior by actually storing the array instance and looking closer at its prototype chain:

[image]

Below verifies that the assignment actually creates an own property on `array1` which shadows the inherited property from `Array.prototype`.

```js
function A(){}

var array1 = [];

array1.constructor = A;

console.log(array1.constructor === A);
console.log(array1.__proto__.constructor === Array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.__proto__` is single variable. When you modify it on all the instances its modified. `__proto__` of two different arrays is same.

```js
console.log([].__proto__ === [1,23,3123].__proto__) //true
```

But when you change the `constructor` property of instance of array `[]`. It doesnot change all `__proto__` of all the instances.

```js
console.log([] === []) //false
```

But if you store an array in variable and then change its property it will work.

```js
let arr = [];
arr.constructor = function A(){}
console.log(arr.constructor)
```